# How to stop ConEmu launching new process from taskbar?

Tags: windows-10, conemu

When I click on the ConEmu icon in the Windows Taskbar, it launches a new tab (containing the default bash.exe).   Is there anyway to stop this so that it just switches to the window I was using?

Comment: In _Settings_ → _General_ and _General_ → _Appearance_, is _Single Instance Mode_ ticked? Under _Appearance_ is _Multiple consoles in one ConEmu window_ ticked? IIRC, it's one of those three. Also, either the `?` in the _Settings_ window header or the [man pages](https://conemu.github.io/en/TableOfContents.html) may be helpful _(ConEmu has one of the most extensive man page collections I've come across)_.

Comment: But if you click an Icon on the Taskbar, you either run the application (if it was not started before), restore the application (if if wasn't focused) or minimize the application (if it was focused). So, from your description I do not understand the problem.